# General commands for getting help and/or documentation for command line utilities in terminal on macOS?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, utilities, documentation

Some command line interfaces or command line utilities give some *comprehensive documentation* or help when `--help` is appended to the name of the command, for example `git`:

```
git --help
# shows comprehensive help docs
```

Some others show *only the command and its arguments* (that's all), for example `grep`:

```sh
grep --help
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

And others give some assistance, but only because `--help` is not recognised as a legal option, for examples `ls`:

```sh
ls --help
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-@ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1%] [file ...]
```

and `netstat`:

```sh
netstat --help
netstat: illegal option -- -
Usage:  netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]
    netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
    netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgRtS]
    netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
    netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
    netstat -m [-m]
    netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
    netstat -rs [-s]
```

#### Question

Are there any generally safe way(s) of getting documentation or help with a CLI or utility without having to google (i.e. from *within* the terminal)? I currently try `--help` or `-h`, but other than that I go straight to google, but would like to know if there are other things to (safely) try before going to google.

Comment: Have you heard of using the `man` command. For example: `man ls` or `man grep`. You can get comprehensive documentation on `man` by entering `man man`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I've never used it before, but my eyes have been opened! Thank you!

Comment: @DavidAnderson I just tried for all of the examples above (`git`, `grep`, `ls`, `netstat`) and it works for all of these different CLI's/utilities. I didn't anticipate that it would be that straight forward. Thanks again

Comment: Try using the mouse to highlight the command, then right click on the highlighted text and select `Open man page`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson wow, didn't know about that either. Just tried with `git clone` and it didn't work but `git-clone` worked, I guess hyphens must be put in place between app and command?

Comment: The highlighted text can not contain spaces.

Comment: @DavidAnderson please feel free to make all of the above into an answer if you feel so inclined. It certainly solved my conundrum

Comment: @stevec In general, man pages correspond to main commands (e.g. `diskutil`, `launchctl`, etc), and if there's a subcommand level that page will include info on those subcommands (`diskutil list` is described in `man diskutil`, `launchctl enable` in `man launchctl`, etc). In a few cases, the subcommands are split out into their own man pages (e.g. `git`, `openssl`), but the naming isn't very consistent; generally you should check the main page first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you heard of using the `man` command. For example: `man ls` or `man grep`. You can get comprehensive documentation on `man` by entering `man man`.

Some of the basic keys used by the `man` command are the <kbd>f</kbd> key to page forward, the <kbd>b</kbd> key to page backward and the <kbd>q</kbd> key to quit.

Try using the mouse to highlight the command, then right click on the highlighted text and select `Open man page`. See example below.

[image]

> Note: The highlighted text can not contain spaces.

Some commands are builtin. This means the command is part on the current shell. If you are using the `zsh` shell (which is the macOS default shell), then you will need to enter `man zshbuiltins` for documentation.

Comment: With `zsh` you can enable the `run-help` mechanism that will display `zsh builtin` help.

Comment: @fd0: Is not `run-help` just an alias for `man`? Or, is there something more that I am missing?

Comment: @DavidAnderson `run-help` shows documentation for functionality that's built into the shell rather than being provided by a binary (eg `export` vs `ls`), see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282649/301421

Comment: Yes, it is like an alias for man, unless you load the function into your current session. In this case run-help will first search for "help" files before attempting to display a manpage.

Comment: For shell built-ins, use `help`: e.g. `help alias`, `help export` etc.

Comment: @alexis: I understand `help` works for `bash`, but `help alias` and `help export` do not seem to work when using the current default macOS shell which is `zsh`.

Comment: Thanks, I should have specified bash... disappointing that zsh doesn't support `help`.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using [`apropos`](https://ss64.com/osx/apropos.html) to "search the [*whatis*](https://ss64.com/osx/whatis.html) database for strings" that can help find the right command.

Use the `-t` option of `man` to "format the manual  page" in a manner that `Preview.app` can display:

```
man -t apropos | open -f -a Preview.app
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An analogous action for obtaining a man-page, described in the answer by @David Anderson, above, can be performed with a shell function that leverages the special URL, `x-man-page` and the `open` command. This allows viewing man-pages in a Terminal session without taking over the Terminal window from which `man` was requested. Instead, a new window will be opened to display the man-page contents.

With `bash`, add this to your `~/.bashrc` file; with `zsh` add the same to `~/.zshrc`:

```
function xmanpage ()
{
    if [ $#   -eq 1 ]; then
        open x-man-page://$1;
    elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
        open x-man-page://$1/$2;
    fi
}
```

If only a name is passed to the function, the man-page for section-1 (user commands) is returned. To select man-pages from another section, specify the section number of the object, followed by the name in interest. For instance, to see the `stat` command information:

```
xmanpage stat
```

And to see the `stat` system call details from section-2 of the man-pages, do:

```
xmanpage 2 stat
```